# font change for chapter, section, subsection titles

Tags: xelatex

So, i am struggling to change the font for title/section/subsection in latex.

Here is my code :

```
% !TEX TS?program = pdflatexmk

\documentclass[fontsize=12pt]{book}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{mathpazo}

%changing font of section/chapter title
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\newfontfamily\headingfont{Papyrus}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\LARGE\headingfont}
\titleformat{\section}{\LARGE\headingfont}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\Large\headingfont}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}{\large\headingfont}



\title{my report}
\author{user name}
\date


\linespread{1.5}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\maketitle
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\tableofcontents
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\chapter{introduction}
text : intro
\section{first section}
text :  section
\subsection{this subsection}
text :section
\subsubsection{this and that subsection}
text :subsub
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
```

And this is the output: 
[image]
The font is only implemented in the `chapter` and `subsection`. Not for others. 
And also the numbering is lost. For example, without `titlesec`and `fontspec` this is what it looks like. The chapter and subsection numbering is lost with that. 
I cant find the bug. (also kind of annoying to use fontspec as it could not find the default latex font, so had to copy paste the `otf` file in the working directory)

[image]